# Windows 8 Store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime

I just have a general question I haven't been able to find the answer to.  If you buy an application in Windows 8 Store(Using your Surface for example.) do you have to purchase that same application on Windows 8 Phone store?

Also if you buy something in Windows phone 7 do you get that same application in Windows 8 Store(Using your Surface for example.) or Windows Phone 8 Store?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. You'd probably find this gets a better response on SuperUser.com.

Comment: Yes, this was not a computer question.  Not sure why I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Windows 8 Store and the Windows Phone Store are separate.  There is only one Windows Phone Store - it just filters the applications based on the version of the phone targets. If you buy a WP7 app, it will be available to you on a WP8 phone.

Comment: So even if I purchase it on WP7 I don't have to purchase it again on any WP8 device?  Just want to make sure I understand your response.

Comment: As long as you use the same Microsoft account on the WP7 and WP8 devices, you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Applications are separate, unfortunately, between Windows Phone and Windows 8. Buying something on Windows Phone 7 will give you that app on Windows Phone 8, however.